# Jenkins build job execute jobs in parallel how to create the programmatically without creating pipeline in jenkins GUI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have 2 functions which I like to execute them in parallel, each job will run on slave or where there are enough resources. the problem is that I dont want to create pipelines in Jenkins GUI and then from that pipeline to execute my function. i like to be able to create the pipeline on the fly in code.
this is example what i have now :

```
//downstream job
build job: "my_job_pipeline_1",
parameters: [string(name: 'PROJECT_NAME', value: "${PROJECT_NAME}"),
propagate: false,
wait: true


//downstream job
build job: "my_job_pipeline_2", 
parameters: [string(name: 'PROJECT_NAME', value: "${PROJECT_NAME}"),
propagate: false,
wait: true
```

This called from my main pipeline but for this to work I have to create 2 pipelines in Jenkins GUI
my_job_pipeline_2 and my_job_pipeline_1
can i create those pipelines programmatically ?

Comment: I guess Jenkins Job DSL Plugin can help you here. You can call jobDSL plugin with pipeline job dsl and your pipeline will create job on the fly

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.pipelineJob

Comment: can be.. is this plugin standart ? can i see the job progress in the logs ?

Comment: This is standard plugin and widely used. You can manage/create/delete jobs using jobDsl Multiple ways. There is a pipeline steps also which will work in your case. When called, you can see the links to created job in console. As per your requirement, You create the job, call/build it and than delete the job again.

Comment: just to verify, can i execute the jobs in parallel?

Comment: im getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipelineJob' found among steps

Comment: @Krishnom please check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114279/calling-pipelinejob-from-groovy-script-returns-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no

Answer (score 0):

The [Jenkins CLI](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#common-commands) allows you to create jobs from the terminal. Follow the documentation to set it up. Under Manage Jenkins > Jenkins CLI you can find the available commands (including "create job")

Comment: i need it from within the groovy code , and also be able to view the progress in the log